# How to make this verbatim code look nice?

Tags: beamer, verbatim

I am doing some slides using Beamer.

One of this slides is pure code

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{verbatim}
> dim(X)   #dimension of our matrix X
[1]  2194 12276
> length(Y) # length of out output y
[1] 2194
> cv=cv.glmnet(X,Y,nfolds=10) # run 10 folds CV 
> cv$lambda.min  # The optimal value of lambda 
[1] 0.02664502
# Beta are the coefficient estimated by lasso
> beta=coef(cv,"lambda.min") 
> which(beta!=0) # which coefficient are estimated non 0
 [1]     1    23    90   393   726   824  1343  1432  1451  1526  1527  1569  1574
[14]  1797  1952  2048  2106  2110  2118  2121  2122  4094  4101  4103  5944  6519
[27]  6524  6525  6542  6544  6545  6546  6839  7026  8283  8318  8321  8322  8323
[40]  8328  8364  8637  8638  8643  8644  8699  8701  9025  9028  9031  9249  9254
[53]  9255  9754  9755  9906  9921 10102 10103 10105 10175 10177 10193 10204 10243
[66] 10260 10261 10300 10306 10636 10934 11077 11078 11294 11295 11297 11299 11300
[79] 11423 11436 12018 12082 12221 12222 12223 12248
> length(which(beta!=0))# how many are estimated non 0
[1] 86
\end{verbatim}

\end{frame}
```

I would like to make this slides more readable and nicer. Is there any easy way to do that?

I have tried

```
{\color{blue}\begin{verbatim}
 ....part 1...
\end{verbatim}
}

{\color{red}\begin{verbatim}
...part 2 ....
\end{verbatim}
}
```

But I do not have enough space to use this approach.

Comment: That's a lot of numbers for a slide. You probably don't expect your audience to read them all. Consider replacing most of the table with an ellipsis ... - that together with the other answers here should improve readability.

Comment: For future questions: Please always post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to consider using `minted`. It offers syntax highlighting for GNU R through the external program `pygmentize`.

Make sure that `pygmentize` is in your `$PATH` and typeset the following MWE using `pdflatex -shell-escape`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\tiny
\begin{minted}{rconsole}
> dim(X)   #dimension of our matrix X
[1]  2194 12276
> length(Y) # length of out output y
[1] 2194
> cv=cv.glmnet(X,Y,nfolds=10) # run 10 folds CV 
> cv$lambda.min  # The optimal value of lambda 
[1] 0.02664502
# Beta are the coefficient estimated by lasso
> beta=coef(cv,"lambda.min") 
> which(beta!=0) # which coefficient are estimated non 0
[1]     1    23    90   393   726   824  1343  1432  1451  1526  1527  1569  1574
[14]  1797  1952  2048  2106  2110  2118  2121  2122  4094  4101  4103  5944  6519
[27]  6524  6525  6542  6544  6545  6546  6839  7026  8283  8318  8321  8322  8323
[40]  8328  8364  8637  8638  8643  8644  8699  8701  9025  9028  9031  9249  9254
[53]  9255  9754  9755  9906  9921 10102 10103 10105 10175 10177 10193 10204 10243
[66] 10260 10261 10300 10306 10636 10934 11077 11078 11294 11295 11297 11299 11300
[79] 11423 11436 12018 12082 12221 12222 12223 12248
> length(which(beta!=0))# how many are estimated non 0
[1] 86
\end{minted}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This would be the optimal solution. But can you explain a bit better? Have I to install pygemtize? In their site is seems like a python library.

Comment: This work. It worked also without pygemtize

Comment: @Donbeo Then `pygmentize` is already installed. It doesn't work without it. You're welcome `:-)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\color{blue}\tiny\ttfamily,language=R]
> dim(X)   #dimension of our matrix X
[1]  2194 12276
> length(Y) # length of out output y
[1] 2194
> cv=cv.glmnet(X,Y,nfolds=10) # run 10 folds CV 
> cv$lambda.min  # The optimal value of lambda 
[1] 0.02664502
# Beta are the coefficient estimated by lasso
> beta=coef(cv,"lambda.min") 
\end{lstlisting}
\pause
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\color{red}\tiny\ttfamily,language=R,breaklines]
> which(beta!=0) # which coefficient are estimated non 0
 [1]     1    23    90   393   726   824  1343  1432  1451  1526  1527  1569  1574
[14]  1797  1952  2048  2106  2110  2118  2121  2122  4094  4101  4103  5944  6519
[27]  6524  6525  6542  6544  6545  6546  6839  7026  8283  8318  8321  8322  8323
[40]  8328  8364  8637  8638  8643  8644  8699  8701  9025  9028  9031  9249  9254
[53]  9255  9754  9755  9906  9921 10102 10103 10105 10175 10177 10193 10204 10243
[66] 10260 10261 10300 10306 10636 10934 11077 11078 11294 11295 11297 11299 11300
[79] 11423 11436 12018 12082 12221 12222 12223 12248
> length(which(beta!=0))# how many are estimated non 0
[1] 86
\end{lstlisting}  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

the second slide:

[image]

If you want to change the color of single expressions use:

```
[....]
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\color{blue}\tiny\ttfamily,language=R,escapeinside=`']
> dim(X)   #dimension of our matrix X
[1]  `\textcolor{red}{2194 12276}'
[...]
```

then `2194 12276` will be in red:

[image]

You can use other characters for the escape sequence. I used backtick and tick (accent grave accent ecute)

Comment: This seems goo. Is there the possibility to have code of one color and result of another? for example dim(X) in blue and 2194 12276 in red?

Comment: see my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fancyvrb`, for general verbatim blocks and `adjustbox` for the ones that are too wide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\scriptsize,formatcom=\color{blue}]
> dim(X)   #dimension of our matrix X
[1]  2194 12276
> length(Y) # length of out output y
[1] 2194
> cv=cv.glmnet(X,Y,nfolds=10) # run 10 folds CV 
> cv$lambda.min  # The optimal value of lambda 
[1] 0.02664502
# Beta are the coefficient estimated by lasso
> beta=coef(cv,"lambda.min") 
\end{Verbatim}
\pause

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{BVerbatim}[fontsize=\scriptsize,formatcom=\color{red}]
> which(beta!=0) # which coefficient are estimated non 0
 [1]     1    23    90   393   726   824  1343  1432  1451  1526  1527  1569  1574
[14]  1797  1952  2048  2106  2110  2118  2121  2122  4094  4101  4103  5944  6519
[27]  6524  6525  6542  6544  6545  6546  6839  7026  8283  8318  8321  8322  8323
[40]  8328  8364  8637  8638  8643  8644  8699  8701  9025  9028  9031  9249  9254
[53]  9255  9754  9755  9906  9921 10102 10103 10105 10175 10177 10193 10204 10243
[66] 10260 10261 10300 10306 10636 10934 11077 11078 11294 11295 11297 11299 11300
[79] 11423 11436 12018 12082 12221 12222 12223 12248
> length(which(beta!=0))# how many are estimated non 0
[1] 86
\end{BVerbatim}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]